# NG-ZORRO range-picker set hour for start date at 00:00:00 and for end date at 23:59:59

Tags: angular, date, time, date-range, ng-zorro-antd

Having [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jj7xzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts), how can I set the hours of the start date and end date to 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 respectively?

I don't really want to set this manually like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  dateRange = [];

  onChange(result): void {
    this.dateRange[0].setHours(0,0,0);
    this.dateRange[1].setHours(23,59,59);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is purely visual you could use pipes instead (https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

***EDIT: one function for multiple editors***

You can use one `onChange(result)` call with every `nzOnCalendarChange` date range you have. Then instead of changing the `this.dateRange` change `result` as it should be the date[] of the widget.
Changing `result` will also result in the binding object to change as long as it is a 2 way bind `[()]`

Comment: For the visual part I could just change the format of the range-picker but in my case I want the actual model value to have those hours set to 00:00 and 23:59

Comment: i think your solution would be the easiest way to automate it. If you do not mind the user changing the time then you could always enable `nzShowTime`

Comment: I see. The issue is that in my real use case I have to write a lot of code to make this work as I want (multiple range pickers that can be undefined). I have lots of `if` statements :(

Comment: hmm if i understand correctly you can use one `onChange(result)` call with every `nzOnCalendarChange` date range you have. then instead of changing the `this.dateRange'` change `result` as it should be the `date[]` of the widget.

if that doesn't work maybe add a sample app onto stackblitz that can be looked at.

Comment: I can do that but the issue is that all my range-pickers are in a form that I send to the backend. Changing the `result` variable means I have to save it somewhere so I can send it to the backend when the user presses the `Search` button. I ended up modifying the dates before I send the to the backend: with tons of if statements :((((

Comment: changing `result` should also change the variable you are binding the component to (as long it is a 2 way bind), so i do not see the issue.

Comment: You are right. The variable I am using changes too if I change the result. Please update your answer so I can accept it since it's your idea (or I can add the answer)

Comment: I accepted the answer since it responds to my question but I found out that my problem is still there because I am using a form. Updating on nzOnCalendarChange doesn't change the form value. I had to use patchValue on the form and it works.